# Receiving "Unknown id: disable" from ADB

Tags: adb

I attempted to apply the following command through ADB...

`adb shell su -c pm disable com.google.android.gsf/.update.SystemUpdateService$Receiver`

But when I enter the command, I receive the following "Unknown id: disable"

What does this mean?

Comment: Don't edit the question to add the answer there. If you want to answer your own question, you can do that by posting an answer.

Comment: Keeping question open, since it has been answered.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't test that, but you didn't quote the command – so `su -c` just got the command `pm` to execute, while everything behind that got passed as additional parameters to `adb shell`. And `shell` doesn't know anything about "disable".

```
adb shell su -c "pm disable com.google.android.gsf/.update.SystemUpdateService$Receiver"
```

should fix that – and pass the complete command (`-c` stands for "execute command") to `su` as *one* parameter.

---

***Notes from the comments:***

Despite of using quotes, you might still get some "unknown id" errors here or there – e.g. as [m0skit0](/users/31842/m0skit0) reports (in now deleted comments) for `adb shell su -c "mkdir /system/priv-app/CoreService"` the error `Unknown id: /system/priv-app/CoreService`. In such cases, play with the quotes: some systems prefer double-quotes, other single quotes, again other are impartial.

And in some cases it seems necessary to use a kind of "section quoting" – so m0skit0's solution was `adb shell "su -c 'mkdir /system/priv-app/CoreService'"` (with the sections `mkdir /system/priv-app/CoreService` (the command to run – parameter to `su`) single-quoted, the `su -c` plus that section double-quoted (parameter to `adb shell`)).